# Incorporating pool while scraping a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, multiprocessing

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/generated/search/quick_search.json"
r = requests.get(url)
contents = json.loads(r.content)
print(contents)
```

I want to grab all the contents of the JSON file and store it into a CSV file, but the problem is that it's taking too long to collect all the information from the file. I want to use multiprocessing Pool to cut down the time, but I don't know how to incorporate it into my code.

Comment: If you're not getting a list of objects from the URL, it's not really possible to multiprocess a dictionary object

Comment: Also, requests has a built in `.json()` function. Use it rather than `.content`

Comment: If you're looking to parse a huge JSON file, you'll need to use a JSON stream parser like [`yajl-py`](http://pykler.github.io/yajl-py/).

Comment: What's too expensive? Looking at the data set, it most definitely shouldn't be in parsing but in the response time. Unfortunately there's not much that you can do about that, unless you're accessing it multiple times in which case you should be caching it.